# Downloading large file on remote host. Then close ssh connection

Tags: bash, ssh, wget

I am trying to download a stackoverlfow dump of all posts to a remote server (actually a container on a remote host). Now as you can image the dump is large (11G). I want to start a download and then be able to exit my SSH connection to the remote host.

I have looked at tmux but it's confusing. 
I know `wget https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z` will work but I will have to stay connected for the duration of the download.

Does anyone know how I can use tmux to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've correctly understood you situation, using `nohup` to launch the command will do the trick.

```
nohup wget https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z
```

This will prevent the killing of the wget process when the shell terminates. 
You can connect via SSH, execute the above command and exit. It will keed downloading by itself.

By the way: Tmux stands for *Terminal Multiplexer* and it's not related to the life cycle of a process.